# GConf Error under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gconf

I use Ubuntu 10.04, and every now and then I start getting the following messages when starting gedit, for example.

> GConf Error: Failed to contact
>   configuration server; some possible
>   causes are that you need to enable
>   TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you
>   have stale NFS locks due to a system
>   crash. See
>   http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for
>   information. (Details -  1: Server
>   ping error:
>   IDL:omg.org/CORBA/COMM_FAILURE:1.0)

I did some searching and read suggestions to `rm ~/.dbus*` or `mv ~/.gconfd/saved_state ~/.gconfd/.saved_state` but these do not work for me.

Comment: Some people write that it may be due to /tmp mounted as tmpfs - does this aply in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Did you

```
rm ~/.dbus*
```

or

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.dbus/*
```

There was an issue in older distributions of Ubuntu that the .dbus directory was owned by root.  Check the output of:

```
cd $HOME
ls -ld .dbus
```

Check whether or not the directory is owned by root.
Should look like this:

`drwx------ 3 userid usergroup 80 2010-08-21 13:37 .dbus/`

10.04 made it owned by the user for 9.04 it was owned by root(instead of userid).  If it is in fact owned by root it should be removed.

Comment: What should they do after checking this output?

Comment: @SimonSheehan Just edited the post.

Comment: Thanks, good work! Perhaps you could also explain how to check if its owned by root?

Comment: @SimonSheehan In a few hours.  Ubuntu access restricted at the moment. :)

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for taking time to help improve :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is generally caused by a permissions issue cause by users running commands like:

```
sudo gedit some_text_file
```

the correct command to use is:

gksu gedit some_text_file

Note: On some distros gksudo or gksu are interchangeable. At any rate, you can generally fix this by doing:

```
sudo chown -R username:usergroup /home/username
```

Generally, username and usergroup will be the same value on most Linux distributions. Hope this helps.

NOTE: The only reason `chown -R` is prefixed with `sudo` is becuase it is likely that root level permissions are set on a file that should be owned and controlled by your user.

Cheers! ~Chris